# Creating new dataframe using weighted averages from dataframes within list

Tags: r

I have many dataframes stored in a list, and I want to create weighted averages from these and store the results in a new dataframe.  For example, with the list:

```
dfs <- structure(list(df1 = structure(list(A = 4:5, B = c(8L, 4L), Weight = c(TRUE, TRUE), Site = c("X", "X")), 
                                      .Names = c("A", "B", "Weight", "Site"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame"), 
                      df2 = structure(list(A = c(6L, 8L), B = c(9L, 4L), Weight = c(FALSE, TRUE), Site = c("Y", "Y")), 
                                      .Names = c("A", "B", "Weight", "Site"), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")), 
                 .Names = c("df1", "df2"))
```

In this example, I want to use columns `A`, `B`, and `Weight` for the weighted averages.  I also want to move over related data such as `Site`, and want to sum the number of `TRUE` and `FALSE`.  My desired result would look something like:

```
result <- structure(list(Site = structure(1:2, .Label = c("X", "Y"), class = "factor"), 
    A.Weight = c(4.5, 8), B.Weight = c(6L, 4L), Sum.Weight = c(2L, 
    1L)), .Names = c("Site", "A.Weight", "B.Weight", "Sum.Weight"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))


    Site    A.Weight    B.Weight    Sum.Weight
1   X       4.5         6           2
2   Y       8.0         4           1
```

The above is just a very simple example, but my real data have many dataframes in the list, and many more columns than just `A` and `B` for which I want to calculate weighted averages.  I also have several columns similar to `Site` that are constant in each dataframe and that I want to move to the result.

I'm able to manually calculate weighted averages using something like

```
weighted.mean(dfs$df1$A, dfs$df1$Weight)
weighted.mean(dfs$df1$B, dfs$df1$Weight)
weighted.mean(dfs$df2$A, dfs$df2$Weight)
weighted.mean(dfs$df2$B, dfs$df2$Weight)
```

but I'm not sure how I can do this in a shorter, less "manual" way.  Does anyone have any recommendations?  I've recently learned how to `lapply` across dataframes in a list, but my attempts have not been so great so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to create a function that works for a single data.frame, then use `lapply` to iterate across your list. Since `lapply` returns a list, we'll then use `do.call` to `rbind` the resulting objects together:

```
foo <- function(data, meanCols = LETTERS[1:2], weightCol = "Weight", otherCols = "Site") {
  means <- t(sapply(data[, meanCols], weighted.mean, w = data[, weightCol]))
  sumWeight <- sum(data[, weightCol])
  others <- data[1, otherCols, drop = FALSE] #You said all the other data was constant, so we can just grab first row
  out <- data.frame(others, means, sumWeight)
  return(out)
}
```

In action:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(dfs, foo))
---
    Site   A B sumWeight
df1    X 4.5 6         2
df2    Y 8.0 4         1
```

Since you said this was a minimal example, here's one approach to expanding this to other columns. We'll use `grepl()` and use regular expressions to identify the right columns. Alternatively, you could write them all out in a vector. Something like this:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(dfs, foo, 
                      meanCols = grepl("A|B", names(dfs[[1]])),
                      otherCols = grepl("Site", names(dfs[[1]]))
                      ))
```

Comment: Thanks Chase, I understand much better now and was able to make this work in my larger dataset.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

using `dplyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library('devtools')
 install_github('hadley/tidyr')
 library(tidyr)

 unnest(dfs) %>%
           group_by(Site) %>% 
           filter(Weight) %>% 
           mutate(Sum=n()) %>%
           select(-Weight) %>% 
           summarise_each(funs(mean=mean(., na.rm=TRUE)))
```

gives the result

```
 #  Site   A B Sum
 #1    X 4.5 6   2
 #2    Y 8.0 4   1
```

Or using `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 DT <- rbindlist(dfs)
 DT[(Weight)][, c(lapply(.SD, mean, na.rm = TRUE), 
                Sum=.N), by = Site, .SDcols = c("A", "B")]
 #   Site   A B Sum
 #1:    X 4.5 6   2
 #2:    Y 8.0 4   1
```

#### Update

In response to @jazzuro's comment, Using `dplyr 0.3`, I am getting

```
   unnest(dfs) %>% 
             group_by(Site) %>% 
             summarise_each(funs(weighted.mean=stats::weighted.mean(., Weight),
                    Sum.Weight=sum(Weight)), -starts_with("Weight")) %>%
             select(Site:B_weighted.mean, Sum.Weight=A_Sum.Weight) 

  #    Site A_weighted.mean B_weighted.mean Sum.Weight
  #1    X             4.5               6          2
  #2    Y             8.0               4          1
```

Comment: I had `summarise_each_q(funs(weighted.mean(., Weight)), list(quote(-Weight)))` But, I could not handle `Weight` in this way. Is it possible to apply different funs to specific columns in `summarise_each_q`? For example, can we apply `weighted.mean(., Weight)` for A and B, and `sum()` for `Weight` in `summarise_each_q`?

Comment: @jazzurro  `summarise_each_q` is deprecated in `dplyr_0.3`. I couldn't get success using `summarise_each_` for specific columns.

Comment: Ah is that right? That is something good to know. Thank you for the update.